# Do we need a plot tag?

Tags: discussion

Currently, 7 questions are tagged as [plot](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot), which is the 3rd most on the site (behind Naruto and Manga). I'm worried that it seems like a very large portion of questions could have something to do with the plot. I also can't imagine that the tag would be useful for very many people. Perhaps a few odd people who are trying to avoid any kind of spoilers would ignore it, but that seems about it from my perspective.

Does the tag [plot](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) serve any useful purpose, or is it a meta tag? If it is useful, what criteria should be applied when judging whether or not to use it? Does the question need to be about a central plot element, or is asking about anything related to the plot good enough to use the tag (presumably this will eventually go in the tag wiki)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In theory, most questions on here will be about plot. I think it will be noise we don't need. It also doesn't serve to describe what the question is about any better. So, while I don't think it is necessarily meta, I think it is unnecessary.

Comment: I agree.  [tag:anime] and [tag:manga] serve to determine which you are talking about.  For [tag:plot], there's not really a "no-plot" tag you could add to give more insight into a question either way.

Comment: agreed, I started to remove the plot tag from questions

Answer (score 2):

Agree, let's use:

- [plot-explanation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) for questions about the plot. We can use the same tag wiki [Movies SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/plot-explanation/info) does.
- [plot-inconsistency](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-inconsistency) for plot holes and the like. Same from [Movies SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/plot-inconsistency/info).

Comment: I originally had that tag on my question, then it was edited out. I suppose I should add it back?

Comment: @Mysticial Who edited it out? Well, let's wait until we all agree first. :P

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/27/revisions

Comment: @Mysticial Ah I see, but you used "disconnect", right?

Comment: Not that it matters since I wasn't expecting the exact names to be static while we're still in private beta.

Comment: I originally used "plot-details" on my first question, but it was edited down to just "plot" shortly (and now it's gone completely, leaving only the series tag). The two tags suggested here sound good to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it could exist. It should, however, be used only in circumstances such as plot-holes. But for that, maybe it should be renamed... So, maybe there should not exist a [plot](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) tag, but rather a [plot-hole](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-hole) tag. No?

**EDIT:**
On the other hand, if I had some question regarding the plot ('Why did X do Y?' or 'Was it relevant to the plot that X did Y?'), I guess the [plot](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) tag could be useful. I think maybe, rather than deleting it, we should think about its wiki.